# Returning an Observable from Angular method including pipe, switchMap, forkJoin

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need the following code to return an `Observable<ApiResponse>`. I'm not sure if this is possible or I need a different approach?

```
private doRequestProducts() {

        const sequence$ = this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrlOverview, {} { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
        switchMap(res => {
          if (res.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error('Value expected!');
          }
          const productResponse: productOverviewResponse = {... res.body.data};
          const responses: Observable<ApiResponse>[] = [];
          productResponse.Products.forEach((item, index) => {
            const response: Observable<ApiResponse> = this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrlDetail, {
              productID: item.productId,
            });
            responses.push(response);
          });

          return forkJoin(responses).pipe(
              map(d => {
                const items: product[]  = [];
                d.forEach((api) => {
                  if (api.status === 'ok') {
                    const invResp: product = {... api.data};
                    items.push(invResp);
                  }
                });
              })
            );
          }
        ));
      }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this code is doing now? (2 http post requests?) And what you need for it to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement of the doRequestProducts function. Besides that I think the approach looks totally fine, but could use some minor improvements. However, please use map instead of the foreach+push approach.

Suggestion:

```
private doRequestProducts(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrlOverview, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
        tap(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error('Value expected!');
            }
        }),
        map(res => res.body.data.Products),
        switchMap(products => {
            const productResponses: Observable<ApiResponse>[] = products.map(product => this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrlDetail, { productID: product.productId }));
            return forkJoin(productResponses);
        }),
        map((responses: ApiResponse[]) => responses.filter(response => response.status === 'ok').map(response => response.data)),
    );
}
```

Additional info:

- It wont return an `Observable<ApiResponse>`. It will return an Observable of an Array with the type of the data Object. I named this Type Data in my example.
- It seems you have a kind of generic API response which you map every time you use it. You might want to consider to create a mapper from ApiResponse to any Type you require to receive more type safety